# 7z Command Line Extraction Issue

Tags: 7-zip

I am getting a "Can not open the file as archive" error when extracting files with wildcards via command line. Any ideas? The End goal is to extract all rar files in download directory recursively.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -r G:\Download\File1.rar          Works
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -r G:\Download\ *.rar             Fails
```

Files are in structure of:

```
file1.00
file1.01
file1.02
file1.rar
File2.00
File2.01
File2.02
File2.rar
```

Comment: `e -r G:\Download\ *.rar` has a space before the path.  Is this intended?

Comment: After testing this on my own machine.. this is almost certainly your problem.  `7z e -r *.rar` just worked on my local machine without errors.  I have 7z in my path (which has nothing to do with your error)

Comment: Thank you, the space was the issue.

Comment: No probs!  A common  mistake. :)